# How to Generate Tables as New Columns Instead of Rows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, html-table

Here's the **index** I've been working on. I'd like for each new table the _form generates to be added horizontally with new columns instead of vertically down. Any suggestions?

I'd like it to go from #1 to #2

**TABLE #1**

NAME (METRIC)

DATE RESULT

NAME (METRIC)

DATE RESULT

NAME (METRIC)

DATE RESULT

**TABLE #2**

NAME (METRIC) | NAME (METRIC) | NAME (METRIC)

DATE RESULT   | DATE RESULT  | DATE RESULT

```html
<!-- Default bootstrap panel contents -->
<div id="values" class="panel panel-default">

  <div class="panel-heading"><h4><b>AVERAGE</b></h4></div>

  <!-- Table -->
<table>
  <thead>
    <% @averaged_quantifieds.each do |averaged| %>
      <% if averaged.user == current_user %>
      <tr>
        <th class="value">
        <%= averaged.name %>
        (<%= averaged.metric %>)
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="category">
        <%= averaged.date.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") %>
        </th>

        <th class="value">
        <%= averaged.result %>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Most of the questions you come to SO with show that you have not done even basic research. I recommend you use google and fiddle around with the code a bit more before asking questions. In this case reading up on tables and their HTML syntax will certainly be a good idea. It will also allow you to learn a lot more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating new rows on every iteration of the loop. Rather than creating new rows and cells on every iteration, you should create only new cells inside loop. This might come at the cost of having to use more than one loop.

Comment: Sorry but how can I do this? I swear I google a lot of this but I have a really hard time finding the answer. This question alone I've prob spent 3 hours on.

Comment: `<tr>` signifies a table row and `<td>` a table cell. Simply loop over your collection (@averaged_quantifieds) inside the `<tr>--Loop here--</tr>` and create a new `<td></td>` on each iteration.